# .NET downloaded and installed, but not in registry?

Tags: .net

I'm looking to update from .NET 4.0 to 4.5. I've installed it, I can see it Programs and Features, but even following a restart, but I can't find the relevant folder under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET, nor is it in the registry:

```
dir /b /ad /o-n %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v?.*

v4.0.30319
v3.5
v3.0
v2.0.50727
v1.1.4322
v1.0.3705
```

How can I confirm that it has been installed correctly and is the version of .NET being used by applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, .net 4.5 overrides the 4.0 assemblies with updated 4.5 assemblies. There is no folder v4.5 in `%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\`.

The best way to check installation is using Registry as said [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx)

Check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`

`DWORD` value named `Release` is

- 378389 for .NET Framework 4.5
- 378575 for .NET Framework 4.5.1 Preview