# .NET 4.5 installion - Environment.Version differs from Product version?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

Following on from [my early question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401515/net-downloaded-and-installed-but-not-in-registry/), I'm doing some further verification not only of the installed .NET version but also how various applications are running on it.

If I bring up IronPython and fetch the value of System.Environment.Version, I get 4.0.30319.**18052**. Yet when I check the properties of System.dll, *Product Version* and *File Version* are given as 4.0.30319.**18021**

How so? Clearly they are both referring to .NET 4.5, but why/how the different revision numbers?

Comment: Pure speculation, but maybe System.dll simply didn't need to change between 18021 and 18052, and so wasn't redistributed?

Answer (score 2):

Technically `Environment.Version` gives you the version of the mscorlib assembly.  It's difficult to always update mscorlib simply to keep a version # up to date when code changes occur in other assemblies (like System.dll) so updates to other assemblies that get pushed to your computer mean they will have higher version numbers than mscorlib.  I think this makes Environment.Version fundamentally broken; but that's what's happening.